# ARToolKit 6 lag

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, artoolkit

When I run the example program that comes with the ARToolKit 6 SDK on an iPhone it has a ridiculous amount of lag. I tried running on both a 5s and a 6, I think it might be a rendering issue, seeing as the 3D cube sticks very well to the marker. Has anyone had a similar issue? If so have you found a fix? Thanks!

Comment: you can also try to get an answer on the community forum: https://artoolkit.org/community/forums/index.php

Comment: Yes I too faced the same issue... Really disappointed

Comment: @Thor_Bux I tried the community forum and have not got an answer yet.